# Change Grid Item Colour on Click

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to make a bingo board tracker. not sure if this is the most effective way to do this but this what I have. I am using a grid to create the board. the goal is that when I click a grid item it will change colour. so far I have been able to change the colour of a block of items if they are given the same class using :

If there is a way to load the specific "item" name, that would be best just not sure how to do that. here is the rest of the code.

I have also read some people are changing the class on click but I don't know if that would work here.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var div = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var nodelist = div.getElementsByClassName("item");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
    nodelist[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  }
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Bingo Board</h1>

<p>press the reset button</p>
<div id="myDIV">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="itemb">B</div>
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>  
    <div class="item4">4</div>
    <div class="item5">5</div>
    <div class="item6">6</div>
    <div class="item7">7</div>
    <div class="item8">8</div>
    <div class="item9">9</div>
    <div class="item10">10</div>
    <div class="item11">11</div>
    <div class="item12">12</div>
    <div class="item13">13</div>  
    <div class="item14">14</div>
    <div class="item15">15</div>
    ...
    <div class="item75">75</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` is the specific name. Please have a look on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).

Comment: i dont know if i am using your solution right but it does not seem to work to change items 1 through 75. i changed the div to an ID:

 <div id="item" onclick="myFunction()">B</div>
  <div id="item" onclick="myFunction()">1</div>

in doing this it only seems to effect the B nothing happends when i click the others. i am not sure if there is a syntax for passing the id name into the function so that i could reuse the same function.

Comment: i have figured it out.
<div id="itemb" onclick="myFunction(id)">B</div>

function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }